# RESTful API endpoint for adding/removing array elements?

Tags: api, http, mongodb, rest

I have RESTful API built on top of a MongoDB store, so it's nice that you can store arrays. It's straightforward to create a new resource like this:

`POST /users`

`{
  items: [
    1001, 1002, 1003
  ]
}`

But how would the HTTP endpoint for adding a new item or removing an item would look like?

Right now, I have to specify the entire array, including elements that I don't want to touch:

`PATCH /users/{id}`

`{
  name: 'Bruce Wayne',
  items: [
    1001, 1002
  ]
}`

Or pass in a mongodb query directly:

`PATCH /users/{id}?query[$push][items]=1003`

Is there a better way to do this?

Edit:

I like how [StackMob's API](https://developer.stackmob.com/sdks/rest/api#a-arrays_and_relationships) does it. How do I update the `name` and remove an element from `items` at the same time though? For example, when I'm updating a bunch of the user's details on an admin dashboard? I don't think replacing the entire array is a good idea in mongodb?

Comment: What are you using for the RESTful API? MongoDB doesn't have an out-of-the-box API that is intended for general use (it's for Admin's only). Further, it's not recommended for production use: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security/#rest-api

Comment: I've clarified the question (there's an Express app on top of mongodb)

Comment: For starters, I'd definitely avoid passing a mongodb query into a RESTful call. That can be a pretty significant security hole as someone could pass in an unexpected query that damages your data.

Comment: Are you asking how best to structure your API calls or how to perform mongodb queries that modify an entry instead of replacing the whole thing?

Comment: @thehiatus How to design the API endpoint on a high level, not the implementation details

Comment: POST user/{id}/item/{item}  for adding item to an array and DELETE user/{id}/item/{item} for removing item from array

Answer (score 29):

Passing a mongodb query seems like a bad idea. Depending on your backend implementation it could lead to an attacker doing bad things to your data as in [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

You can model the modification of an attribute on a resource with PUT or PATCH with some limitations:

- When using `PUT` the client is expected to send the whole representation of the resource. IT works for you but it may be cumbersome.
- When using `PATCH` the client is expected to send the attributes that are intended to change, instead of the whole resource. Yet, you have to send **the whole value**, not just the additions or deletions of items to the value. Again it works but you are not in love with it.

I think you are looking for a way to model adding and removing items to the array:

1. I would model the array as a resource on its own: `/users/:id/items`
2. Accept `POST`to add an item to the array and `DELETE` to remove from the array.

It's simple and RESTful.

Comment: The above methods is good, when working on a single item, either creation or deletion. How to structure the API, when I have to create/delete multiple items at once?

Comment: what if i have array items for user: { userId: 1, items: [1,2,3] } and just i want to remove "item = 2 & item=3"? In delee i can' set up "body".

Comment: But you can identify items in the array by their index in the array used in the URI path `DELETE` `/users/:id/items/:index`.

Answer (score -1):

As per the REST standards to create and delete a new request -->
POST -Create a new resource in a collection
and
DELETE -Delete a resource

I can give you an example of how the high-level HTTP endpoint in java looks like using Jersey.
You can have a Resource class with the HTTP Path specified and specific Paths for methods doing different operations.
So the URL could look like --
/rest/MyResource/Resource accompanied by a request JSON or XML(that contains your input data)

Here is a sample Resource class that would be your entry point(ofcourse you would have to do your configuration in web.xml to do URL mapping for this class) -->

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SampleRESTServiceResource {

    /**
     * @param incomingJsonString
     * @return Response 
     */
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createNewResource(JSONObject myJson) {
        // Do a call to a DAO Implementation that does a JDBC call to insert into Mongo based on JSON
        return null;

    }

    /**
     * @param incomingJsonString
     * @return Return response 
     */
    @DELETE
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response deleteResource(JSONObject myJson) {
        // Do a call to a DAO Implementation that does a JDBC call to delete resource from  Mongo based on JSON
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you want to try out an example you can refer to this page -->
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-tomcat/

Comment: It's not addressing the question about high-level endpoint design for mongodb arrays, nothing to do with specific Java implementation.

Comment: I thought it is specifically answering this question -->
"But how would the HTTP endpoint for adding a new item or removing an item would look like?"
So i gave an example of how it would look like in Java.

Comment: HTTP endpoint here refers to the specific HTTP method, URL and body content, like "POST /users" with body "{id:1, name:'John'}"

Comment: that is what i have given my friend.. :) specific HTTP methods createNewResource(for POST) and deleteResource(DELETE) as endpoints in java (although i haven't given example of having content in body) ..

Comment: When we talk about methods in this context it is not Java methods or any language methods but HTTP Methods. Maybe that has been part of the confusion.